# How can I access a variable outside executeSql function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, web-sql

How can I access the `url` variable outside of the executeSql function? (commented where I want it)

```
function generateUrl(id, callBack){
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Marktplaats", 200000);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {

    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM searches, settings', [], function (tx, results) {
         var url = "http://google.nl";
    }, null);

    //I want to access the url variable here
    });
}
```

Comment: wrongly tagged question..?

Comment: Why is it wrongly tagged?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Sort of :) - WebSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're suggesting doesn't make sense as `executeSql` is asynchronous.

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM searches, settings', [], function (tx, results) {
     var url = "http://google.nl";
     // This is executed 2nd
}, null);

//This is executed 1st
});
```

Therefore at the point of your comment, it's impossible for `url` to have a value.

What you should be doing, is using that `callBack` parameter you have to pass the `url` back to the caller:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM searches, settings', [], function (tx, results) {
     var url = "http://google.nl";
     callBack.call(this, url);
}, null);
```

Then you can call `generateUrl` as:

```
generateUrl(15, function(url) {
    // URL is visible now
    console.log(url);
});
```

Comment: I wanted to add another query and extend the url variable with the values of it. I guess I just have to call the function that way then and extend it there. Thanks!

Comment: @SinanSamet You can absolutely do that, but you need to do it from inside the `executeSql` callback.

Comment: Yes I was already using the function that way for another purpose. But I thought maybe it would be possible to add the second query in the function and I didn't know executeSql was asynchronous, thank you for telling me :)